# When is the month in a Date-object zero indexed

Tags: javascript

I know, because zero indexed month, for the date

```
Thu Mar 02 2017
```

I have to write

```
new Date(2017, 2, 2);
```

The same if I use a variable

```
var thismonth = 2; new Date(2017, thismonth, 2);
```

But, if I say

```
var thisday = [2017, 2, 2]; new Date(thisday);
```

I get a result with a one indexed month

```
Thu Feb 02 2017
```

This means, I can use the array-vars like the date-vars in the real life

```
var thisday = [2017, 3, 2]; new Date(thisday);
```

and get the (un)expected result

```
Thu Mar 02 2017
```

Thats nice, but confusing! Why this behaviour? Is there a rule?

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting find! However there is no documented Date constructor that accepts an array of values such as `[2017, 3, 2]`, so what you are getting in this case isn't something you should rely on.

You can see that among your examples, only the first one is documented:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the code does what you think it does. The Date constructor does not accept arrays. Quoting the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date-constructor)

> Let v be ? ToPrimitive(value).
>
> If Type(v) is String, then
>
> Let tv be the result of parsing v as a date, in exactly the same manner as for the parse method (20.3.3.2). If the parse resulted in an abrupt completion, tv is the Completion Record.

which means you actually pass `2017,3,2` as a string. Now what happens to that string? Well, check the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.parse) again.

> Otherwise, parse interprets the resulting String as a date and time; it returns a Number, the UTC time value corresponding to the date and time. The String may be interpreted as a local time, a UTC time, or a time in some other time zone, depending on the contents of the String. The function first attempts to parse the format of the String according to the rules (including extended years) called out in Date Time String Format (20.3.1.16).

Interesting, another link to the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format)

Your format doesn't follow the `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` format or date only `YYYY-MM-DD` which means we're back to the previous spec section which says

> If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats.

So basically you should not rely on it. Depending on the JS engine/browser the date might not be parsed at all. It looks like V8 accepts not only colons/dashes as separators, but also commas, which is why it works.

Edit: found it

https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/68960eeb763f93dcedb37d5b663b1019192b7f36/src/builtins/builtins-date.cc#L115

which calls

https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/68960eeb763f93dcedb37d5b663b1019192b7f36/src/dateparser-inl.h#L16

which has plenty of comments and weird stuff to keep searching if you want.